# Get QTreeview index from text slug

Tags: python, search, pyside, qtreeview

I'm trying to retrieve the model index for the QTreeView item using the given slug - which is a single string representing the treeview item's hierarchy separated by hyphens. In this case, I want to get the model index for the given slug `'Vegetable-Carrot-Blackbean'`:

[image]

My current function always returns "Vegetable" and I feel like the way it's written I'd expect it to continually loop through a given index's children until it fails, returning the last found tree item:

```
import os, sys
from Qt import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class CategoryView(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(250,400)

        self.categoryModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.categoryModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Items'])

        self.categoryProxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.categoryProxyModel.setSourceModel(self.categoryModel)
        self.categoryProxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.categoryProxyModel.setSortCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.categoryProxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)

        self.uiTreeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.uiTreeView.setModel(self.categoryProxyModel)
        self.uiTreeView.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiTreeView)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


    def appendCategorySlug(self, slug):
        parts = slug.split('-')
        parent = self.categoryModel.invisibleRootItem()
        for name in parts:
            for row in range(parent.rowCount()):
                child = parent.child(row)
                if child.text() == name:
                    parent = child
                    break
            else:
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(name)
                parent.appendRow(item)
                parent = item


    def getIndexBySlug(self, slug):
        parts = slug.split('-')
        index = QtCore.QModelIndex()

        if not parts:
            return index

        root = self.categoryModel.index(0, 0)
        for x in parts:
            indexes = self.categoryModel.match(root, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, x, 1, QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)
            if indexes:
                index = indexes[0]
                root = index

        print index, index.data()
        return index


def test_CategoryView():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = CategoryView()
    ex.appendCategorySlug('Fruit-Apple')
    ex.appendCategorySlug('Fruit-Orange')
    ex.appendCategorySlug('Vegetable-Lettuce')
    ex.appendCategorySlug('Fruit-Kiwi')
    ex.appendCategorySlug('Vegetable-Carrot')
    ex.appendCategorySlug('Vegetable-Carrot-Blackbean')
    ex.appendCategorySlug('Vegan-Meat-Blackbean')

    ex.getIndexBySlug('Vegetable-Carrot-Blackbean')

    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    test_CategoryView()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your current implementation doesn't work is that the `start` argument of `match()` needs to be valid index. The invisisble root item can never be valid because its row and column will always be `-1`. So, instead, you must use the the model's [index()](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#index) function to try to get the first child index of the current parent. You also need to make sure that an invalid index is returned when ***any*** part of the slug cannot be matched, otherwise you could wrongly end up returning an ancestor index.

Here's a method that implements all that:

```
def getIndexBySlug(self, slug):
    parts = slug.split('-')
    indexes = [self.categoryModel.invisibleRootItem().index()]
    for name in parts:
        indexes = self.categoryModel.match(
            self.categoryModel.index(0, 0, indexes[0]),
            QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, name, 1,
            QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)
        if not indexes:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
    return indexes[0]
```

As an alternative, you might want to consider returning an *item* instead, as that will then give you access to the whole `QStandardItem` API (and the index can be still be easily obtained via `item.index()`):

```
def itemFromSlug(self, slug):
    item = None
    parent = self.categoryModel.invisibleRootItem()
    for name in slug.split('-'):
        for row in range(parent.rowCount()):
            item = parent.child(row)
            if item.text() == name:
                parent = item
                break
        else:
            item = None
            break
    return item
```

But note that this returns `None` if the slug cannot be found (although it could easily be tweaked to return the invisible root item instead).

Answer (score 1):

In this case the convenient way is to iterate over the children recursively:

```py
def getIndexBySlug(self, slug):
    parts = slug.split("-")

    index = QtCore.QModelIndex()

    if not parts:
        return index

    for part in parts:
        found = False
        for i in range(self.categoryModel.rowCount(index)):
            ix = self.categoryModel.index(i, 0, index)
            if ix.data() == part:
                index = ix
                found = True
        if not found:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
    return index
```